# Is there a way to bypass the 500ms delay on explicit waits with selenium and python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

For explicit waits in the [selenium python docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) it says:

> By default, WebDriverWait calls the ExpectedCondition every 500 milliseconds until it returns success.

I notice the by default at the start of the sentance. Is there a way to bypass this 500ms delay? Can i set it to something like 100ms? Is this possible?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the official [WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) function

You may simply set the `poll_frequency` to another value rather than 0.5, so for your case you may use `poll_frequency=0.1`.

This code will be an example with your wished frequency (taken from [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits))

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, poll_frequency=0.1).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks! I never really look on selenium.dev. I will keep that in mind next time I have a question.